# TensorFlow - Multiple Possible Labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, prediction

I'm creating a **Tic Tac Toe** engine as my first `Machine Learning` project. It's job is to predict the best move on each position. The thing is, in some positions, there might be several *"best-moves"*. So I want to provide these best moves to `TensorFlow`, and then if the model predicted any of them, it will count it as **true/correct** prediction.

**My question is: Is that possible? If yes, how to implement it? And if no, is there any workarounds?**

Note: I'm using `TensorFlow` with `Python 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which model are you using, but one solution could be:

- treating a label of every row as a n^2 dimensional vector (number of fields in your tic-tac-toe grid, in the most usual case: 9 as n is 3)  where a value of 1 indicates whether the move is desired in this position and 0 otherwise, e.g. `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]` could indicate that the desirable moves would be in two bottom corners of the grid
- the output of the last layer of your model could be fed through the sigmoid function
- then the loss of your model during training could be a [cross-entropy loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) ([here](https://gombru.github.io/2018/05/23/cross_entropy_loss/)'s an example of a writeup on this topic). You don't want to feed the output through a softmax function as it maps the output values of model to probabilities which sum up to one - hence assumes that there's only one most desirable label.

For loss function you could leverage [log-loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/log_loss) which is a weighted sum of binary cross-entropies for all labels separately (by default). [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.14.0/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py#L444) is the exact definition if you want to go into details (it's often good to take a look at TensorFlow's source code to get your head around how it exactly works).

EDIT: The assumption here is that the model should output **all** correct moves at once so depending on what exactly you want to achieve that might not be the best solution for you as you mentioned the model predicting **any** of the correct labels. But maybe it'll lead you towards your goal :)